# mocking a aws service inside a function in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to mock AWS service in python.

Usually, I mock AWS service which is defined globally.

But is it possible to mock, if it is defined inside the function?

eg.

```
def somefunction(replication_region):
   s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name=replication_region)
```

This is a common function, which will be invoked if there are replication region is present for s3, if replication region is not present, then only one region will be executed.

So this variable is not defined globally.

Comment: Just mock `boto3.client`? then the mocked return value will be the value of `s3`.

Comment: boto3 has mocking support built in. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143597/mocking-boto3-s3-client-method-python for some details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking boto3 S3 client method Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143597/mocking-boto3-s3-client-method-python)

Comment: there is also the [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) package

Comment: I am using patch, I am not able to access the variable inside the function