# How to unit test a boto3 lambda client invoke function

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, boto3

Completely unsure and can't find much information on how to unit test a response from a boto 3 lambda client, especially seen as i need to decode the response that comes back as it is stored in an object. Here is an example of something like the function i would like to unit test

```
def get_attachment(my_id):
    payload = {"myId": my_id}
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName=os.environ["MY_LAMBDA"],
        Payload=json.dumps(payload),
    )
    response_content = json.loads(response["Payload"].read().decode())
    return response_content["claim"][0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response payload is encoded in an object. Specifically, it is a `StreamingBody` object. Your mock response must also return a `StreamingBody` object so that it can call `.read()` and decode it.

```py
import io
import json
import os

import mock
from botocore.response import StreamingBody

@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"MY_LAMBDA": "some_lambda"})
@mock.patch("path.to.get_attachment.lambda_client")
def test_get_attachment(mock_lambda_client):
    mocked_response_payload = json.dumps({'claim': ['foobar']}).encode("utf-8")
    mock_lambda_client.invoke.return_value = {'Payload': StreamingBody(io.BytesIO(mocked_response_payload), len(mocked_response_payload))}
    response = get_attachment('some_id')
    assert response == 'foobar'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various boto3 mocking efforts:

- [Mocking boto3 client methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143597/mocking-boto3-s3-client-method-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143597/mocking-boto3-s3-client-method-python/37144161#37144161)
- [spulec/moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto)